# SharePoint Migration Effort Estimation

Tags: sharepoint, migration, data-migration

We are planning to migrate SharePoint 2013 content to 2016.As part of migration, we have to migrate huge amount of data. We got migration effort estimation from third party which is purely based on data size. They have considered data size migration/per day with X number of machines .For example, 5 machines x 1 day = 10 TB.

total effort = Total Data Size/  1 Day output

I'm not convinced with this approach, here is my questions.

1. Is SharePoint content migration completely depends on size of data?
2. How about tools like metalogix plays role in migration?
3. Is there any tool/formula to estimate SharePoint migration?

Answer (score 0):

A SharePoint migration isn't necessarily based on data volume. Look into other 3rd party tools as some provide unlimited migration.

Here's a comparison matrix of the major ones: http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/sharepoint-comparison-matrix-for-3rd-party-migration-tools

Answer (score 0):

Migration of contents across SharePoint servers does not necessarily based on the volume of data, of course volume is also one of the factors. Below, I have listed out some of the factors where the content migration rely on

1. Number of elements (site / list / folders and documents) consider for migration and structure of the contents
2. Number of metadata values you are going to carry forward and how complex they are ?
3. Number of user, in case if you are interested in migrating permissions

There is no standard formula to estimate the effort needed for SharePoint migration. They completely rely on the above mentioned factors.